# Should range hood ducting be installed before cabinetry?

Tags: hvac

When should I install range hood ducting? I am putting in new cabinets. The kitchen has never been vented outside before. The duct work needs to be installed above the cabinets. What needs to be done first, cabinets or duct?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do things in either order but make things easier on yourself and prepare the ducting and needed cutouts before hanging the cabinets.

Comment: Ducting is usually installed even behind drywall. It would be a real chore to do it after cabinets.

Comment: that's what I thought.  Am I correct in thinking that the duct work can be hidden behind the crown molding (is realistic?)  Does the duct work contain it's self.  Does duct work leak? This is a residence with average cooking usage.

Comment: You want to route the ducting, using the range hood manuf. recommended size via a route that gets you to where it needs to go with minimal disruption of the structure.  Yes, you should be able to hide it behind crown molding if that's present in your kitchen.  No, it should not leak!

Answer (score 1):

You want to install the duct work first. You'll be going through the walls and or through the ceiling and trying to do this after the cabinets are install is a pain. you also then take the change of damaging the new cabinets in the process. Ideally, do them both at the same time if it's possible because then you can totally coordinate exactly what needs to be done. This works if you're doing the work yourself but might be difficult if you've got contractors doing it.

Comment: I will be using different contractors for both jobs..