# Can range hood venting ductwork be hidden behind crown molding?

Tags: ducts

Installing a range hood in older home going out the side wall.

Am I correct in thinking that the duct-work can be hidden behind the crown molding? (is realistic?)

Does the duct-work contain itself? Does duct-work leak? This is a residence with average cooking usage.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Crown molding itself won't hide much, but a chase up the wall to cover ducting may have crown molding on it. Whether the duct leaks is up to your workmanship.

Comment: See this, as this has been answered: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/183969/97780

Comment: Are you asking about a horizontal run of duct? Normally a range hood duct goes straight up to the attic, either behind or over the wallboard. If your situation is different, please revise your question to make that more clear.

Comment: revisions:  the duct will run horizontal to leave the house.. the complete path will be:  leaving the range hood vertical (10 inches) w/1 90* angle, to the right for 10 feet to outside.. the Hvac guy going to do the work, wife is being nasty toward me quote "we'll see, he is very busy" that is why I'm not asking him these questions.  He said my brother and him will get it done.  I am looking for new Hvac guy!

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here... duct work for a range hood normally follows the same restrictions as a dryer.  The air is expected to be hot, so you need a sealed metal tube for it to flow through.  You can't use plastic or wood or any other combustible or meltable materials.  In practice, the air probably isn't much hotter than the ambient temperature of the house, but you have to build it to assume the air could be very hot.

The second issue is that the blower on a hood is not meant to deal with much pressure in the duct.  That means the duct needs to be fairly large.  A small economy vent hood might get away with a 4" round duct, but they normally use 5" or much larger for a "professional" model.  Even large crown molding would only hold a 2" pipe, and even that is a maybe.

Comment: yes, because if you have a grease fire on the stove, the air will be very hot.